# D3 incomplete rendering of data series when using transitioning animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi when attempting to animate in a new line graph (data) series replacing the existing line graph (data) series for some reason for some countries I get an incomplete line.

To see what I mean please visit the following and select for example "Sweden" https://bl.ocks.org/angusgrant/raw/8599b573d600539f192d9c5709bc1e6e/6bb1a4f028a231fcc84f8fd9dc2f05d3c3365cd6/  the graph redraws but not all the lines reache the length of the x axis. However if you refresh the page (having had local storage enabled in your browser) you should see that the graphs are complete.

What i see:
[image]

What I expect to see and what I see if i reload the graph:
[image]

Please advise I'm using D3 v5 and I am new to D3. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the `stroke-dasharray`. If you will observer the svg path of each line, you can see the `storke-dasharray` attribute is not getting calculated correctly. The `storke-dasharray` length is calculated for the very first country and remain same for the rest of the selected countries. As you might be aware that `storke-dasharray` is used to define patterns and gaps of a shape. I can think of two approaches:

- You can remove the `stroke-dasharray` transition function but that
  will also remove initial animation.
- Recalculate the `stroke-dasharray` length for each selected country:

  `const t = d3.transition().duration(500);
   const line = svg.selectAll('.commodities').data(commodities);
   line
      .select('.line')
      .attr('d', d => lines(d.values))
      .call(transition);`

Comment: or remove the `stroke-dasharray` attribute at the end of the first transition

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever looked at the Javascript Console

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL46.314431632…".
Error: <text> attribute transform: Trailing garbage, "translate(2410,NaN)".
```

Looking in the `path`s for this chart it is related to the `Other` data line. It is never visible. The reason

```
    {description: 'Other', kpppd: +d["Other(FAO (2017)) (kilocalories per person per day)"]},
    // column name:                   Other (FAO (2017)) (kilocalories per person per day)
```

---

A possible solution for the transition problem is removing the `stroke-dasharray` attribute at the end of the line animation.

```
function tweenDash() {
    const l = this.getTotalLength();
    return d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
}

function transition(path) {
    path.transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
        .on("end", function () { d3.select(this).attr("stroke-dasharray", null); });
}
```